# Drupal Content Access and if anomynous show login block

Tags: users

I have this website where every pages are viewed by anonymous users.

I want to create a new page (and add it to the menu) where **only the authenticated users** can have access to it.

I installed Content Access module but somehow it does not work...

**What I want is this: If it is an authenticated user - show page. 
If not, show login block, and then redirect to the page.**

I installed Rules module as well but I don't know how can that help me at all...

Thank you in advance, hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends what method is used to create the page. Pages that  are created by the Views module define the permission settings in the "Access" configuration, as does page manager. But it sounds this is just a typical node page. Content Access should do the trick, but if not, you may want to try the [Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module instead. Be sure to read the README on these modules, as they usually require you to rebuild permissions after enabling and configuring them. The permissions of the node should be understood by the menu system, so restricted pages will not appear to un-authorized users, which should satisfy the need to hide the menu item. If un-authorized users do land on the page somehow (such as yourself, after clicking a bookmark after your session has expired), then you can try something like the "Redirect 403 to User Login" module Although, in my opinion, the more sensible option might be to [simply define your default 403 (Access denied) page as the login page](https://www.drupal.org/node/15366). The only reason not to do this might be if you are trying to obscure the login process from anonymous users for some reason.

Comment: OK, Content Access is now working and I plan to do what you suggested... I just have this small problem, as you said: "which should satisfy the need to hide the menu item" - this is a problem for me, i want to display the menu item... So un-authorized users land on the page for sure and I offer them the possibility to login. How can I do this? I searched and this was a problem 5 years ago... isn't there a simple solution by now? Thank you for you help

Comment: @Drii7, I understand what you are saying now. Yeah, the menu permissions can be a double-edged sword like that. Perhaps you can define a redirect to the page under access control, and then define the menu item to link to the redirect?